# Windows 10 does not find an executable on PATH

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line

I have a fresh install of Anaconda3 and python 3.7 in Windows 10. In cmd,

```
echo %PATH%
```

includes

```
C:\Users\Adam\Anaconda3;C:\Users\Adam\Anaconda3\Scripts
```

This first folder contains python.exe and I can execute it from there. However,
invoking python (or python.exe) in any other directory results with "not recognized as an internal or external command". Why? (Anaconda path is added to the User path, not system path).

ELABORATION: System reboots don't help. I added Anaconda3 and Scripts path to system path (at the beginning of it) and it didn't help. When I invoke python from other than Anaconda3 folder, windows opens a window suggesting an install from microsoft store. When I invoke conda from other than Scripts folder, I get a message that it doesn't exists. (I can open python and conda fine from their folders.)

Answer (score 1):

> Invoking `python` (or `python.exe`) in any other directory results with "not recognized as an internal or external command". Why?

Path variables often need to be reloaded in order to function correctly.

For instance, if you update your Windows environment variables to add a new path, you can usually use that path immediately (ex. to call executables) from a command window spawned at your desktop. However, `explore.exe` needs to be reloaded before those variables are usable elsewhere (e.g. spawning a command window from within Explorer). This is part of the reason why logging off or rebooting is often recommended after updating your environment.

> The Anaconda path is added to the User path, not system path.

It might be worth considering adding Anaconda to your System Path. Items available only to certain users may not be available in all instances.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get more in the error message?

For example...
"Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases."

Go over to those alias settings and switch off alias for python.

Worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).